# How to set Font in itextSharp for HTML to PDF

Tags: unicode, itext, truetype, html2pdf, indic

I have to create run time pdf from html in Web application developed in VB.Net and MSSQL 2005, using itextSharp.

The HTML is saved in database. which contains Gujarati, Hindi and English contents.

Can anyone tell me how to set font for the html and which fonts should I use that display Enlgish, Gujarati and Hindi 
I tried Arial Unicode MS but its does not display Hindi accurate.

Thank you in advance

here is the code of method that i am using to convert html string into pdf file which user can save on local machine.

```
Private Sub ExporttoPDF(ByVal FullHtml As String, ByVal fileName As String)
    Try
            Response.Clear()    ' Clear Response and set content type and disposition so that user get save file dialogue. 
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}.pdf", fileName))
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)


            Dim sr As StringReader = New StringReader(FullHtml)
            Dim pdfDoc As iTextSharp.text.Document = New iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate, 10, 10, 10, 10)
            Dim htmlparser As HTMLWorker = New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
            pdfDoc.Open()
            Dim fontpath As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\fonts\ARIALUNI.TTF" 
            '  "ARIALUNI.TTF" file copied from fonts folder and placed in the folder
            Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontpath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)

            FontFactory.RegisterDirectory( System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath , True)

            FontFactory.Register(fontpath, "Arial Unicode MS")
            FontFactory.RegisterFamily("Arial Unicode MS", "Arial Unicode MS", fontpath)    

            'parse html from String reader "sr"
            htmlparser.Parse(sr)
            pdfDoc.Close()
            Response.Write(pdfDoc)
            Response.End()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here is how I am using the code

```
dim htmlstring as string = "<html><body encoding=""" + BaseFont.IDENTITY_H + """ style=""font-family:Arial Unicode MS;font-size:12;""> <h2> set Font in itextSharp for HTML to PDF  </h2> <span> I (aneel/અનિલ/अनिल) am facing problem to create a pdf from html that contains enlish, ગુજરાતી, हिंदी and other unicode characters.  </span> </body></html>"         
ExporttoPDF(htmlstring ,"sample.pdf")
```

In result 
for Gujarati it is displaying અનલિ  where as expected is અનિલ

Where as for Hindi it is displaying अनलि  where as it should be  अनिल .

Comment: a soultution for this problem by Vinit_Patel from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423993/itextsharp-htmlstring-to-pdf-unicode-are-missing

Answer (score 1):

try

```
pdfDoc.Add(New Header(iTextSharp.text.html.Markup.HTML_ATTR_STYLESHEET, “yourcssfile.css”)) // or path to your css file
```

then

```
Dim styles As iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet
styles = New iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet
styles.LoadTagStyle("ol", "leading", "16")
```

you can add everything to styles. then replace html.parse with this

```
HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StreamReader("htmlpath.html", Encoding.Default), styles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you're out of luck. **[See here](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/83)**. Basically, the iText developers have put out calls many, many times for code contributions to support the ligatures necessary to properly display Indic languages in PDF, but no one has volunteered to help.

Comment: thank you for reminding me my responsibility i.e. not alwasy try to use developed thing only, also give something to the community.
I'll try my best to develop a  ligatures  for Inidic language. Although I am not native speaker of indic language, but once I have worked for Urdu language about 12 years ago. I hope my that knowldge and experience might help me for developing ligatures for Indic language.

Comment: That would be **great** if you could contribute to the project. If you decide it's something worthwhile, please subscribe to the [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/itext-questions) for more information for how on how to submit your code.

Comment: @Aneel Mehta, I know you would make people **very, very happy** if you did that! As kuujinbo said there are many, many requests for this.

Comment: @AneelMehta - Saw you post on the mailing list :) Good luck!